# Accessing type inside std::pair passes as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I want to write a function

```
template <class T>
X foo (T);
```

where `T` is of type `std::pair<X, X>`.

How can I deduce the return type `X` from `T`?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour when `T` is not a pair? How about if it is a pair of two different types? Should they work in some unspecified way? Should they fail at instantiation time? Should they fail at substitution time?

Answer (score 3):

In your example X has to be templated, too:

```
template <class T, class X = typename T::first_type >
 X foo (T t);
```

But better would be:

```
template <class T >
 typename T::first_type foo (T t);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
template <class T>
T foo ( std::pair<T, T> bar );
```

Now `T` is the type you are looking for (i.e. `X` in your question).

**Answer to comment:**
If you cannot change the function signature have a look at [std::tuple_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/tuple_element), or as PiotrSkotnicki pointed out, simply use

```
typename T::first_type
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That work theoretically work, but the function is part of a larger library, I can not change the function signature

Comment: @1v0 then how do you imagine changing the return type?

Comment: @Haatschii how is `std::tuple_element` better here than `typename T::first_type` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: It is probably not, thanks for bringing it up.